# Can't install Virtual Shield on Ubuntu 20.04 due to dependency problems

Tags: package-management, software-installation, vpn

I have been trying to install Virtual Shield on Ubuntu 20.04 but whenever I try to it has an error and then it corrupts the installer making it impossible to install and uninstall programs.

Virtual Shield has a Linux version, it's supposed to be for Ubuntu but I don't know what version. It's a deb file and I tried installing it through the Software program and through the terminal.

Every time I have tried to install it, it gives me a vague error message saying it couldn't be installed but each time it had partially installed it. The Virtual Shield icon would appear in the list of programs but wouldn't open when clicked.

Is there a special way to install it or can I use the VPN network proxy settings under Ubuntu's network settings to connect to the Virtual Shield VPN?

I just tried to install it with gdebi and it came up with errors again... gdebi-gtk says

> Could not install all dependencies - Usually this is related to an error of the software distributor. See the terminal window for more details.

Looking in the terminal window, it starts getting errors when trying to do something called "mono-complete". It says

```
dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-complete: 
  mono-complete depends on mono-devel (= 6.8.0.105+dfsg-2); however:
    Package mono-devel is not installed
```

but if I try to install it, it says mono-devel is installed already.

There are also some other error messages..

```
dpkg: error processing package mono-complete (--configure): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up mono-4.0 service (6.8.0.105+dfsg-2) ...
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure. 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mono-xsp4-base
mono-xsp4-base depends on mono-devel; however:
Package mono-devel is not installed.
```

It goes on more than that.. says that `mono-apache-server4`, `mono-fastcgi-server4`, and `monodoc-viewer` are also not installed.

Comment: It would really help if we knew the complete, exact wording of the error that you are encountering, and what leads you to believe that it had "*partially installed*"

Comment: I can't install it either, and the people at Virtualshield don't reply to my email.
This is not software that I would recommend!